# How to redisplay mysql records without reloading/refresing the current page using php?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

So here's the scenario:

The code below display all the user accounts.

```
<table border="3px" align="center" cellspacing="3px" cellpadding="3px">
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td>Password</td>   
<td><a href="" onclick='return popup_link()'>Add</a></td>       
</tr>
<?php
include("connection.php");
$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Then I have a popup page wherein it can add user account into the database table user account without reloading the page itself.

```
<form id="form">
<h3>Add Record</h3>
<label>Username:</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Userusername"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Password:</label>
<br/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<?php
// Establishing connection with server by passing "server_name", "user_id", "password" 
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database by passing "database_name" and above connection variable
$db = mysql_select_db("smsi_inventory", $connection);

//Fetching Values from URL  
$username2=$_POST['username1'];
$password2=$_POST['password1'];

//Insert query 
$query = mysql_query("insert into tbl_users(username, password) values ('$username2','$password2')");
if($query){
echo "Record Saved succesfully";
}

//connection closed
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

However, I'm having a hard time displaying the records of the newly added accounts without reloading/refreshing the page. Is there a way I can display the newly added accounts using php?

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have to use AJAX for that and keep checking with timer for any new record added in the database.

Comment: You can use ajax/jquery after the form submit. It will display the account without you to refresh the page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response. So I will use AJAX on displaying the records? instead of a simple PHP code?. So, there is no way I can use PHP on displaying records without reloading?

Comment: No, there is no other way. PHP is executed once on the server, the result is sent to the browser and now the server finishes processing your request. Reading new data from your MySQL database requires another PHP request, either through reloading the whole page or an AJAX call

Comment: Alright! Got it! Thanks for all your help and support. You have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'YOUR UPDATE DATA URL',
    data:{your:data},
    success:function(data){
      //WHATEVER YOU SHOW ON SUCCESS
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      alert("Parse Errore");
    }
});
```

For More Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

`mysql` is deprecated you have to use `mysqli`

A few days back I implement this code. I am sharing you the sample, you have to implement in your code This code is working for me.

You have to submit the data to the database and display that data in the table without refresh the page. right?

You have to use the ajax and in the success function, you have to use the `tr: last` and reset the table.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include('connection.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="register" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Lastname">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
<table border="1" style="margin-top: 25px;" id="myTable">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
 <?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['lname']."</td> 
                <td>".$row['email']."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
 ?>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#register').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission

            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + '&lname='+ lname + '&email='+ email;
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:'process.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:dataString,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td>' +fname +'</td><td>'+lname+'</td><td>'+email+'</td></tr>');
                    $("#register")[0].reset();
                },
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```